# how to add the values of drop down using php code

Tags: php, html

I am trying to add the values of the two drop down box.
but it seems there is still wrong in my code.
I don't know to solve this problem, I'm trying to fix this but I still don't get it.
Could someone help me in my problem in terms of this code?

Here's my code:

```
        <td><center>
                <select id="row7" >
                <option value = "0" selected>0</option>
                <option value = "1" >1</option>
                <option value = "2" >2</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><center>
             <select id="row8" class="Drops">
                <option value = "0" selected>0</option>
                <option value = "1" >1</option>
                <option value = "2" >2</option>
            </select>
           </td>    

          <?php
            error_reporting(0);
                $var7 = $_POST['row7'];
                $var8 = $_POST['row8'];

                $total2 = $var7+$var8;
         ?>
         <td><center><textarea name='row12' cols='2'
          rows='1'readonly='true'><?php echo $total2;?>
         </textarea></center></td>
```

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you tell us what behavior you're currently getting.  (Also, most of your first paragraph is just a longwinded way of saying "Find the bug in this code.")

Comment: php posts the `<select>` `name` attribute, not the `id`, so you need to give your elements names -> `<select name="row7" id="row7" >`/`<select name="row8" id="row8" class="Drops">`

Comment: ahy.. cause I don't know what the right term for what i am trying to say.

Comment: You've a lot of missing code.

Comment: ahy.. okay2x @Sean.. thanks

Comment: what's btw @Fred-ii-? i'll put that to the code.

Comment: Somebody did a bad edit, that's why. I will do a rollback @Renren

Comment: @Makyen Your edit created syntax errors. I did a rollback. Please be careful when you edit "code" as to not modify it.

Comment: who's @Makyen? he edited the code?

Comment: Yes, earlier. See this => http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28517699/2 being the edit.

Comment: hehe.. I already saw that code. it seems that there's no changes in the code

Comment: If you want to do math on the same page, you'll need to add `<form>` tags, and a POST method along with a submit button. Otherwise, you'll need to use Ajax/JS.

Comment: okay.. i'll the missing code to my code..

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Thank you for catching any problem (I do see multiple syntax errors). The note `(tidy)` in my edit summary indicates that what I did was use stackoverflow's automatic `Tidy` function to format the code. The syntax error is reproducibly introduced by that operation.  That would be a bug in stackoverflow's code. Is there a good method to report it?

Comment: @Makyen There's a place on Stack/meta to report bugs. I'd find it if you can't, but I have to go. If it's a bug, they'll fix it.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Thanks. I started looking for where to report bugs shortly after posing my above message.  I found what appears to be the appropriate method (report on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) for stackoverflow specific bugs, and [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) for bugs affecting multiple sites; use the `bug` tag in both locations). I will report the bug. It's a bug if the `Tidy` operation is supposed to handle PHP embedded in HTML (a normal occurrence).

Comment: @Renren I've posted something for you below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a PHP solution, where the entire code below is to used inside the same file.

Your present code seems to be missing a few things, such as `<table></table>` and `<form></form>` tags, as well as a submit button.

Plus, the (form) selects require a "name" attribute; you cannot rely on an "id" alone.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<table border="1">
    <td><center>
            <select name="row7">
            <option value = "0" selected>0</option>
            <option value = "1" >1</option>
            <option value = "2" >2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><center>
         <select name="row8" class="Drops">
            <option value = "0" selected>0</option>
            <option value = "1">1</option>
            <option value = "2">2</option>
        </select>
       </td>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// error_reporting(0);

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['row7']) && isset($_POST['row8'])){

                $var7 = (int)$_POST['row7'];
                $var8 = (int)$_POST['row8'];

                $total2 = (int)$var7+$var8;
// echo $total2;
}
?>
     <td><center><textarea name='row12' cols='2' rows='1' readonly='true'>
     <?php if(!empty($total2)) { echo (int)$total2; } ?>
     </textarea></center></td>
    </table>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="ADD">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getValues(){
  var row7 = document.getElementById("row7");
  var row8 = document.getElementById("row8");
  var valueRow7 = row7.options[row7.selectedIndex].value;
  var valueRow8 = row8.options[row8.selectedIndex].value;
  var textarea = document.getElementById("textareaid");
  textarea.innerHTML = valueRow7 + valueRow8;
 }
```

```html
<td><center>
                <select id="row7" onchange="getValues();">
                <option value = "0" selected>0</option>
                <option value = "1" >1</option>
                <option value = "2" >2</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><center>
             <select id="row8" class="Drops" onchange="getValues();">
                <option value = "0" selected>0</option>
                <option value = "1" >1</option>
                <option value = "2" >2</option>
            </select>
           </td>    

          <?php
            error_reporting(0);
                $var7 = $_POST['row7'];
                $var8 = $_POST['row8'];

                $total2 = $var7+$var8;
         ?>
         <td><center><textarea name='row12' width="100px" height = "10px" cols='2' id="textareaid"
          rows='1'readonly='true'><?php echo $total2;?>
         </textarea></center></td>
```

Comment: Why do you have duplicate `var row7`/`var row8` in your `function getValues()`?

Comment: it's okay. its the same output.. hehe

Comment: how to add the value of the two drop down?

Comment: where do you want to add them??

Comment: Maybe you mean something like that `textarea.innerHTML = valueRow7 + valueRow8 + textarea.innerHTML;` instead of `textarea.innerHTML = valueRow7 + valueRow8;`